# Unable to export query results to a new table in google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

[Unable to save query results to a bigquery table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWa8U.png)

I have been facing the issue for a couple of days now and its annoying. I have already tried multiple query locations in EU (due to data privacy regulations, I am limited to EU) and could never seem to save data. Also not getting any errors too.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, but have you tried just doing "create table <<target>> as select * from <<source>>"